# My cards aren't centred inside the React Slick carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, carousel

SETTINGS:

```
const settingss = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
};
```

HTML:

```
<Slider {...settingss}>
         <div>
           <article className="advantages-card">
             <img src={require("../../assets/advantages-icon1.png")} alt="" />
             <h3> {t("Advantages-title1")} </h3>
             <p>{t("Advantages-p1")} </p>
           </article>
         </div>

         <div>
           <article className="advantages-card">
             <img src={require("../../assets/advantages-icon1.png")} alt="" />
             <h3> {t("Advantages-title1")} </h3>
             <p>{t("Advantages-p1")} </p>
           </article>
         </div>

       </Slider>
     </div>
```

RESULT:
[image]

when i use H3's instead of cards, it center them with no problems.
Noe that the "advantages-class" in my cards has a width property that i believe is causing the problem:

```
.advantages-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(11, 117, 51, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 28rem;
  color: var(--color-black);
}
```

when I remove the width from the advantages-card class it becomes centered but it's streched :
[image]

what can I do please to make this work? i want to show a card at a time , centred.
Thank you for taking the time to check this out

Comment: try to replicate this in sandbox.